# When is mean imputation appropriate to deal with missing variables?

Tags: missing-data

Of my 407 observations, 28 do not have data for a variable.

Would it be appropriate to use the mean of the observations I do have to substitute?  What are the pros and cons of this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer does depend on how many variables you have and how interested you are in accuracy.  The answer also depends on if you are dealing with a time series or not.  However, there are a few approaches to your problem...

1. **Using the mean.**  You can fill in missing values with the mean of the variable over the time period of observation.  *Pros*: Easy to compute and understand.  Decent option if you know your variables to be distributed normally.  *Cons*: You if your data has a trend (if the rolling-mean is increasing over time) your added values may make your charting look odd.  Also, this is not acceptable if your variables have an odd distribution that makes the mean value meaningless.
2. **Rolling forward the last value**.  This is generally only acceptable if you have a time series, such that you have sequential observations.  Here, you "roll forward" the last value of the variable into the missing space.  *Pros*: Computationally simple, also easy to understand, very helpful for missing data in time series of asset movements.  *Cons*: You may roll forward an anomoly-type value (outlier) if you are unlucky.
3. **Exclude the observation**.  You can choose to simply exclude any observation with missing variables.  This reduces the total number of observations, obviously.  *Pros*: You are not estimating any data, so you know all of your observations are 100% correct and you are not creating any sort of simulated results.  Also easy to understand and compute.  *Cons*: You lose some information due to the exclusion, which can be harmful to your analysis.  Not useful for datasets with few observations (this is completely subjective, generally you would like $n > 50$).
4. **Simulate the value using distribution of the variable**.  You can use the values you *do* have for the variable in question to determine an approximate distribution of the variable.  Then, use a random generator to simulate a variable out of the distribution you determined.  Alternatively, you could add all variable values into a bag and randomly pull one out, which is less accurate but ensures you are sampling values directly from an observable set of values.  *Pros*: "Fancy", will be theoretically closer to the actual variable values (had they existed and are randomly simulated assuming your observations are $i.i.d.$).  *Cons*: Computationally expensive, requires knowledge of statistics and/or computing, more difficult to explain, assumes your observations are $i.i.d.$.

Comment: thank you very much! The data is cross sectional and not panel. the variable with missing observations has a mean of 99.043 with a standard deviation of 4.3. your saying that i would have to normalise this result somehow before using mean imputation?

Comment: It depends on the distribution of your underlying variable.  If you plot a histogram of all variable values, you will see the distribution.  If it is roughly Gaussian, the mean is an okay bet.  If not, you need to use method (4) above.  As @mdewey mentioned, using the mean will cause a big spike in your distribution for no good reason, which is why simulating variable values is the preferred option.

Comment: The mean and standard deviation themselves have no bearing on whether or not you can use mean imputation.

Comment: the variable is unfortunately not normaly distributed. it is score out of a hundred and most people have around 98 or 99......  is there any reference you could point me towards on your method 4?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question on how to do this, as it is its own question that can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

The disadvantage of single imputation like this is that you impute the same value each time. This means that you (a) put a spike in the distribution for no good reason (b) your data-set has less variability than it should have. If you have only a few observations missing then it may not matter too much but you really need to chase up [multiple-imputation](/questions/tagged/multiple-imputation) for information on much better ways to do this.